# BufferedReader Pending for Request/Response Socket Connection

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to build a simple request/response server.

Client send a message to Server. Then, the server response a message to client.

**Server-side Code**

```
package com.techoffice.example;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.net.ServerSocketFactory;

public class TcpServerAppl {

    static int port = 1010;
    static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    static {
        try {
            serverSocket = ServerSocketFactory.getDefault().createServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Server is running on " + port);
        while(true){
            Socket socket = null;
            try{        
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Someone is connecting to the server");
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();

                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(os);

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                // read message from client 
                String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                while(line != null && line.length() > 0){
                    System.out.println(line);
                    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                }
//              reader.close();

                // send message to client
                System.out.println("Server starts sending message to client");
                printWriter.println("This is a message sent from server");
                printWriter.flush();
//              printWriter.close();

            } catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                if (socket != null){
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Client-side code**

```
package com.techoffice.example;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.net.SocketFactory;

public class TcpClientAppl {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
        // start socket connection
        Socket socket = SocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket("localhost", 1010);
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        // send message to server
        printWriter.println("Send Message From Client" );
        printWriter.flush();
//      printWriter.close();

        // read message from server
        System.out.println("Client starts reading from Server");
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        while(line != null && line.length() > 0){
            System.out.println(line);
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
//      bufferedReader.close();

        // close scoket connection
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

The Server is blocked at the Buffered Reader. However, if I tried to close the Buffered Reader by closing in Print Writer in Client, the Client throw an exception of "Connection Closed".

It is known that closing in PrintWriter or BufferedReader would close the socket connection.

**Update**

Specifying a End of Request/Message would be one of solution. But in this case, I would not want to have an End of Request. I just want to have response for a request no matter no many line is in the request.

Comment: Your update expresses a contradiction in terms. The server has to know where the end of the request is.

Answer (score 1):

> The client throw an exception of 'connection closed'

No it doesn't. If you uncomment the `printWriter.close()` line it will throw an exception '*socket* closed'.

But to your real problem. The server reads lines until end of stream before it sends anything: end of stream will never occur until the peer closes the connection; and the peer *isn't* closing the connection, except as above; so it will never send anything and just stay blocked in `readLine()`; so the client will block forever in `readLine()` too.

As this is evidently an echo server, it should echo every line as it is received.

Comment: It is not a echo server for echoing every line. I think It is more like a simple HTTP Server. Besides, I do not want to specify the end of request / message.

Comment: Well bad luck, you have to, because end of stream will never arrive if the peer wants to receive a response via the same connection. You can use some kind of length word prefix, e.g. `Content-length` in HTTP, or a self-describing protocol like XML, or various other things, but you have to have some way for the server to recognize the end of the request.

Comment: I found that in most case in HTTP Request, the content-length is 0. Is the content length do not count the header content? It only counts request body. How could HTTP Server response if the content length do not match the actual content in request body.

Comment: The content length is the length of the body, which starts after the blank line after the headers. In the case of a GET or HEAD request there is no body, so `content-length` is 0. It is still *required* however. The server reads all the headers until the blank line, then it reads `Content-length` bytes being the request body.

Comment: That means the http client would specify the content length when do a post request to server. Sorry for my foolishness. How would server handle the request if the content length does not match the actual content length (The content length is longer than actual content length)?

Comment: For a HTTP Server, is that mean it cannot bufferedreader to read body content from the request?

Comment: (1) Yes, it means the content-length would specify the length of the POST parameters in the request body. (2) No, it means that it has to read the headers and find the content-length header and act accordingly, as I already stated in my previous comment. If you're looking to emulate HTTP you need a good knowledge of RFC 2616 and successors. If you're designing an application protocol of your own, frankly you need help.

Answer (score 0):

Question is missing exception thrown by client side. Maybe try to close everything (reader,writer) on server-side after your communication is done. BTW. you don't need to call flush before calling close. Also you can use try-catch-withResources with socket on server side

Comment: The server side can't close anything if it is blocked in `readLine()`.